# JSON not working with AJAX? Code included

Tags: ajax, json, cross-domain

Ok so here is my problem...

I am trying to read my JSON located at:

http://allencoded.com/test3.php

But this code isn't working:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script>

    $.ajax({
    url: "http://allencoded.com/test3.php",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        document.write("Day: " + data.gms[i].d);
    }
    }
});




    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

For the fun of it here is the JSON from my php file:

```
{
   "w": 1,
   "t": "PRE",
   "gms":    [
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55425,
         "h": "NE",
         "vnn": "Jaguars",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 12,
         "v": "JAC",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 47,
         "hnn": "Patriots",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081152
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55424,
         "h": "PHI",
         "vnn": "Ravens",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 6,
         "v": "BAL",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 13,
         "hnn": "Eagles",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081151
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55423,
         "h": "SD",
         "vnn": "Seahawks",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 24,
         "v": "SEA",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 17,
         "hnn": "Chargers",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081153
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55426,
         "h": "DAL",
         "vnn": "Broncos",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 23,
         "v": "DEN",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 24,
         "hnn": "Cowboys",
         "t": "8:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081154
      },
            {
         "d": "Thu",
         "gsis": 55427,
         "h": "OAK",
         "vnn": "Cardinals",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 24,
         "v": "ARI",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 18,
         "hnn": "Raiders",
         "t": "10:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081155
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55430,
         "h": "ATL",
         "vnn": "Dolphins",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 28,
         "v": "MIA",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 23,
         "hnn": "Falcons",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081252
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55429,
         "h": "DET",
         "vnn": "Bengals",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "CIN",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 34,
         "hnn": "Lions",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081251
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55431,
         "h": "WAS",
         "vnn": "Steelers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 7,
         "v": "PIT",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 16,
         "hnn": "Redskins",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081253
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55428,
         "h": "KC",
         "vnn": "Buccaneers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 25,
         "v": "TB",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 0,
         "hnn": "Chiefs",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081255
      },
            {
         "d": "Fri",
         "gsis": 55432,
         "h": "NO",
         "vnn": "49ers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "SF",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 24,
         "hnn": "Saints",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081254
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55433,
         "h": "CLE",
         "vnn": "Packers",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 17,
         "v": "GB",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 27,
         "hnn": "Browns",
         "t": "7:30",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081351
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55437,
         "h": "CAR",
         "vnn": "Giants",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 10,
         "v": "NYG",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 20,
         "hnn": "Panthers",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081355
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55434,
         "h": "CHI",
         "vnn": "Bills",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "BUF",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 10,
         "hnn": "Bears",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081352
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55435,
         "h": "STL",
         "vnn": "Colts",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 10,
         "v": "IND",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 33,
         "hnn": "Rams",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081353
      },
            {
         "d": "Sat",
         "gsis": 55436,
         "h": "TEN",
         "vnn": "Vikings",
         "q": "F",
         "vs": 3,
         "v": "MIN",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 14,
         "hnn": "Titans",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081354
      },
            {
         "d": "Mon",
         "gsis": 55438,
         "h": "HOU",
         "vnn": "Jets",
         "q": "P",
         "vs": 0,
         "v": "NYJ",
         "rz": -1,
         "hs": 0,
         "hnn": "Texans",
         "t": "8:00",
         "ga": "",
         "eid": 2011081551
      }
   ],
   "y": 2011,
   "gd": "0"
}
```

I am not sure why this isn't working at all. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"why it's not working"*, please? Also, have you checked that `test3.php` delivers proper headers (`Content-Type: application/json`)?

Comment: I got it working thanks guys! New code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write` should be used only before the page ends loading. You are using it in an Ajax callback.

Comment: Yep that is what I am doing now...Got it working with document write though as you see above. But that is only a temporary fix until I use your solution.